# how to scrape images from facebook group

Tags: dataset, data, scraping, web-scraping

I want to scrape images from several Facebook groups some of them are public and some or not
I am new to web scraping but I tried to look for solutions with selenium or BeautifulSoup or scrappy but I didn't find anything

Comment: You should be able to achieve that with Selenium and/or BeautifulSoup (if used correctly in case of websites like facebook that rely on js). I am not sure what your issue is.

Comment: Facebook uses JavaScript for browser fingerprinting as well as behavioural analysis, which means that they can tell if requests are coming from a bot, and if they are then your access will be blocked.
but if you have something that worked please share

Comment: I did run into this problem once, but was unable to go around it and gave up in the end. In theory it should be possible to fake being a regular user with the right behaviour and setting the right headers in your requests. There are some articles and discussions on stackoverflow on how to do it. Didn't work for me tho and if you decide to keep at it, just be aware that it will not be an easy task.

Comment: Mohamed, were you able to do it?

Comment: unfortunately no :)